# How to iterate over the arguments of type string in the bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

An argument is passed to bash script from outside and is read within bash file. Looks like as follows:

```
  #following is the point from where the argument is passed to config.sh
  controller.vm.provision :shell, path: 'shell/config.sh', keep_color: true, privileged: false, :args => ip
```

inside the config.sh reading the argument. The argument "ip" is somewhat like following:

```
  ip = "10.12.153.26" "10.12.153.25" "10.12.153.24"
```

Now i want to iterate over the above argument inside the bash. so doing as follows:

```
  array=($1) //please note $1="10.12.153.26" "10.12.153.25" "10.12.153.24"
  for i in  ${array[@]}
    do
      echo $i //it is iterated only once and output is "10.12.153.26" "10.12.153.25" "10.12.153.24"
    done
```

So the output i am getting only once and is complete argument as it is but i want it to get displayed one by one so, that i can even use the single value separately for some other purpose. So, please suggest how can i have this?

Comment: They are 3 separate arguments? What is wrong with just `for arg in "$@"
;do
   printf "%s\n" "$arg"
;done` ?

Comment: What do you mean `ip = "10.12.153.26" "10.12.153.25" "10.12.153.24"`??  Run `declare -p ip` and post the output.

Comment: If you were doing this right, your distinct IPs would be `$1`, `$2` and `$3`, not all squashed together in `$1`. Then you could just iterate over `"$@"` to get the full list.

Comment: ...this looks a bit like you're using Chef or such -- there's no reason those tools can't pass a literal array through, instead of squashing it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the value on spaces, you can do like this:

```
set -- $1
for i; do
  echo $i
done
```

If the value of `$i` is `"10.12.153.26" "10.12.153.25" "10.12.153.24"`,
then this will output:

```
"10.12.153.26"
"10.12.153.25"
"10.12.153.24"
```

To get rid of the double-quotes, you could use *parameter expansion*:

```
set -- $1
for i; do
  echo ${i//\"/}
done
```

Comment: how can i have the values "10.12.153.26"
"10.12.153.25"
"10.12.153.24" without double quotes accross them i.e. like first i get 10.12.153.26 then 10.12.153.25 and then other

Comment: Added that to my answer